# Class structure for the proposed data and its containers?

Tags: c#, containers, class-design

First I would like to wish a happy new year to everyone that may read this :)

I am having trouble on how to make a container for some data that I am importing into my application, and I am not sure on how to explain this very well and my english is not really a that good so I hope you can bear with my mistake and help me with some guidance.

Currently with a foreach I am importing the follow fields from the data I receive:
guid, itemid, name, owner(optional, can be null), zoneid, titleid, subid, heading, x, y, z, typeA, typeB, typeC

From the above fields I need to store a Waypoint list of all coords a given item has moved to BUT for each guid I have a new list of waypoints.

And from the waypoint list the first entry is also my initial item start location which would be my item initial position (if you notice i have a separate list for it which I was not sure would be better or not) not all items have a waypoint list but all items have the first position.

So the first idea I came with to store this data was a list with a class with 2 inner classes with their list:

```
public List<ItemList> myList = new List<ItemList>();
public class ItemList
{
    public int GuID { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TitleID { get; set; }
    public itemType Status { get; set; }

    public class Waypoint
    {
        public int Zone { get; set; }
        public int SubID { get; set; }
        public int Heading { get; set; }
        public float PosX { get; set; }
        public float PosY { get; set; }
        public float PosZ { get; set; }
    }
    public List<Waypoint> Routes = new List<Waypoint>();
}
```

**So here is an example of how I would add a new waypoint to a GUID that exists in the list**

```
                    ItemList myItem = myList.Find(item => item.GuID == GUID);
                    if (myItem != null)
                    {
                        int lastDistance = 3;
                        ItemList.Waypoint nextWaypoint;

                            // Add new Coordinates to the given GUID
                            ItemList.Waypoint lastWaypoint = myItem.Routes.LastOrDefault();
                            if (lastWaypoint != null)
                            {
                                lastDistance = getDistance(posX, posY, posZ, lastWaypoint.PosX, lastWaypoint.PosY, lastWaypoint.PosZ);
                                if (lastDistance > 2)
                                {
                                    nextWaypoint = new ItemList.Waypoint();
                                    nextWaypoint.SubID = subID;
                                    nextWaypoint.Zone = zone;
                                    nextWaypoint.Heading = convertHeading(heading);
                                    nextWaypoint.PosX = posX;
                                    nextWaypoint.PosY = posY;
                                    nextWaypoint.PosZ = posZ;
                                    nextWaypoint.Rest = rest;
                                    myItem.waypoint.Add(nextWaypoint);
                                }
                            }
                    }
```

Then to register a new item I would take advantage of the itemExist above so I won't register the same GUID again:

```
                    ItemList newItem = new ItemList();
                    newItem.GuID = GUID;
                    newItem.ItemID = itemID;
                    newItem.Name = name;
                    newItem.Status = status;
                    newItem.TitleID = titleID;

                    // Item location
                    ItemList.Location itemLocation = new ItemList.Location();
                    itemLocation.SubID = subID;
                    itemLocation.Zone= zone;
                    itemLocation.Heading = convertHeading(heading);
                    itemLocation.PosX = posX;
                    itemLocation.PosY = posY;
                    itemLocation.PosZ = posZ;
                    newItem.position.Add(itemLocation);
                    myList.Add(newItem);
```

Could you help me with advices on how my class structure and lists should look like ?

Are there better ways to interate with the lists to get lastWaypoint of a GUID or verify wether an item exist or not ?

What else would you advise me in general ?

PS: If you have any questions or if there is something I missed to post please let me know and I will update it.

UPDATE: have changed the above to reflect what I currently have and if anyone else still have advices I would like to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes (after two glasses of champaign…):

- You don't state any requirements for the data structures and their usage. Your design looks quite reasonable.
- You can use the `FirstOrDefault()` method to check for existence (i.e. the return value `!= null`) of an item and retrieve it from the list in one operation.
- Your code has an apparent bug: there's no `nextWaypoint != null` check before the new waypoint is added and it need not exist. Likewise there shall be no `lastWaypoint != null` check necessary as the list won't contain any null values.
- I'd recommend introducing constructors to your classes accepting values for the mandatory properties.
- There's no clear point of having both a GUID and an integer ID identifying the `ItemList` — the search condition is then just overspecified.
- The commonly used coding standard states that property names shall begin with an upper case letter (`posX` ⇒ `PosX` etc.).
- The `waypoint` and `position` lists should be properties as well; having a getter only and backed with a readonly field.

P.S. Happy new year once it comes into your timezone and a lot of good code in 2011 ;-)

Comment: `You can you the FirstOrDefault() method to check for existence (i.e. the return value != null) of an item and retrieve it from the list in one operation.` but this would not be usable for me, since on the waypoint i dont need the first but the last and before the way I have to search for the item, but it is god to know. `apparent bug` indeed i was rewriting it to post it here and i may have skipped important parts in the process my bad. `I'd recommend introducing constructors` I do have it but I was trying to reduce the size of the post using only the really needed information of my doubts.

Comment: It is almost hehe ;) thanks, yes the properties was a type too + some drinks ... hehe i did copy and paste part of it from my code but rewrote some stuff in the process of posting here and might ended up forgetting it.

Comment: about the `FirstOrDefault` that was a great tip since it leaded me to `LastOrDefault`